# Hadoop MapReduce Output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

another question about hadoop. Is it possible for reducing a list to a map? I mean I have al list like this after the map()

```
KEY:  VALUE:

aaa   word 

      string 

      word 

      text 

      string 

      word
```

is it possible to reduce the list to the following structure?

```
KEY:  VALUE:

aaa   word, 3 

      string, 2 

      text, 1
```

thanks
manuel

Comment: I cannot understand very well the output of the map, sorry. Do you mean you have a (key,value) pair where key=aaa and value=word,string,word,text,string,word?

Comment: yes and for reducing the list of the values I just want to add the number occurrence.in the list.

Comment: Yes it is possible, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is the following: due to you are trying to implement the typical word count but on a list that is associated to a key, I would extend such wordwount example by producing at the output of the mappers (key,value) pairs such as:

```
aaa-word,1
aaa-string,1
aaa-word,1
aaa-text,1
aaa-string,1
aaa-word,1
```

I.e. I would add the `aaa` information to all the output pairs. Then, the reducer would behave as usual: by receiving lists of values whose keys are the same; then, the common key is splited into `aaa` and the word; in addition, the length of the list is returned, which is concatenated to the word.

```
(aaa-word,1),(aaa-word,1),(aaa-word,1)-->(aaa,word-3)
(aaa-string,1),(aaa-string,1)-->(aaa,string-2)
(aaa-text,1)-->(aaa,text-1)
```

Comment: That would be good suggestion. In that way i have both, the Start and the destination, in a readable and  string or text. Thanks a Lot